# Massive viewcount difference

Tags: discussion

**How come most questions barely reach 500 views while some reach upwards of 30k views?**

One explanation is the "Hot Network Questions" section but this doesn't seem like it would cover all cases. This seems very unhealthy to me. It also seems like the workplace is not the only community experiencing this phenomenon.

Comment: Please [do not use backquotes to emphasize text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/). This syntax should be reserved for code or data, not normal text. Abusing code markdown has ugly results, [causes problems](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7437) for parsing tools such as screen readers for the visually impaired, and is easily avoided by using bold, italics or other formatting instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is simply wrong. :o)

[Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law)
[Zipf's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law)
[Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution)

Essentially it says that the normal case is **not** an equally distributed
distribution as laymen would expect, but in fact very few posts with a very
large count, a minority of posts having approximately 80% of all votes and a sizable majority of questions 80% with only 20% of votes. In fact these laws are used to statistically detect human fraud because people do not know how it really works.

Stackexchange groups in general align perfectly with the expected count and are therefore healthy and alive. Sorry for throwing statistics at you at workplace meta, but I could not resist. :o)

Answer (score 1):

Some questions are much more popular from google search results as well.

This is particularly true with older questions that have that many views.

Comment: How about questions like: [Fair treatment for employees always late due to public transport](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/104796/fair-treatment-for-employees-always-late-due-to-public-transport)? Its only 18 hours old and has already gotten almost 34k views. I did a search on the hot network questions and it hasn't even been featured there.

Comment: It seems that I have mixed up the time the question has been answered and the posted time. I can now see why that question would have that many views.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason is coming to the site, I have a link in an email I use all the time, so whenever I come to stackexchange I use it. This means that question has probably a thousand views from me alone. It's my point of entry.